# Inconsistent appearance of ui:inputDateTime

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a simple lightning component with a `ui:inputDateTime` component that I want to use on a record page:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">    
    <ui:inputDateTime label="Date and Time" displayDatePicker="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

I created a simple test application to be able to preview the component in a separate browser tab:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="force:slds">
    <c:AppointmentTasks />
</aura:application>
```

When I view the component on the record page, this is how it looks:
[image]

When debugging and therefore viewing in a separate browser tab, it looks like this:
[image]

Why is the appearance so different? How can I get the component to always look like the one in the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ui` components are not wrapped with the standard SLDS styling by themselves.

Inside a `one.app` container (in Lightning Experience, Salesforce1, and Lightning communities) - `ui` components have the SLDS look and feel, but outside the `one.app` container they do not.

An `aura:application` is not a `one.app` container, this is why your styling does not look good there, and a lightning record home is a `one.app` container.

That is the reason for the look and feel differences.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there an official CSS file I can download and import with `<ltng:require>` so that the look matches? Or would I have to manually style the `ui` components?

Comment: if you use extends="force:slds" - that should be enough, but you need to use the css classes manually. If you do want to use it somewhere else, you can download [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/)